# Javascript/JQuery to add and delete table row by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add and delete rows (by Id) to my table dynamically. The add button works fine but I am not sure why the delete button doesn't work (it's either deletes the last row or doesn't work). Any suggestion please?

Here is my table:

```
<table class="customFiltersTable" id="customFiltersTable">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Javascript add button has this code inside:

```
filtersRow = filtersRow + 1;

var fType1 = $('<tr class="rowTableFilters" id="rowFilters'+filtersRow+'" name="rowFilters'+filtersRow+'"><td class="colFilters" id="colFilters'+column1+'" name="colFilters'+column1+'" width="480px" align="center"></td><td class="colFilters" id="colFilters'+column2+'" name="colFilters'+column2+'" width="480px" align="center"></td><td class="delButton" id="delButton" name="delButton" width="40px" align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="deleteFilter'+filtersRow+'" name="deleteFilter'+filtersRow+'" style="float: right;">Del</button></td></tr>');

$("#customFiltersTable").append(fType1).promise().done(function () {
   $("#deleteFilter" + filtersRow).click(function(){
         var row = document.getElementById("rowFilters"+filtersRow);
         row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
   });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `$("#deleteFilter" + filtersRow).on('click', function(){...}`

Comment: Remove the entire promise logic, `append()` is synchronous.

Comment: @Musa could you please elaborate? If I remove promise logic how to trigger $("#deleteFilter" + filtersRow).click?

Comment: Use `$("#customFiltersTable tbody").append ...`. The way you add rows now, it appends them after the `<tbody>` tag.

Comment: @blgt the rows are added before the <tbody> I can clearly see it. I tried yours and I still have the same problem!

Comment: @Anonymous ...which is why I add this as a comment and not an answer. It's simply better practice. Refer to this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acquaint yourself with jQuery's event delegation, https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/. You'll learn that you can avoid attaching the delete click listener to every row you add, and instead attach that listener once to the table element:

```
$('#customFiltersTable').on('click', 'button', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
});
```

Comment: Simple and perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing filtersRow; however your click function only gets evaluated at the time you press the button.  In other words, this code:

```
function(){
     var row = document.getElementById("rowFilters"+filtersRow);
     row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

is executed **on click** and will run with whatever value of filtersRow you last incremented.  You'll always be removing the last row.

Perhaps something like:

```
function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Sorry, this is compiled in my head.

Answer (score 0):

To add row:

```
var tmp = '<tr id="4_r"><td>row4</td></tr>';
$('#myTable tbody').append(tmp);
```

To delete row have id="4_r":

```
var iddel = "4_r";

$('#myTable').closest('table').find('tbody > tr')
                .each(function(){
                    var idr = this.id;
                    if(idr == iddel){
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
```